# How can I get a notification when my device changes orientation to portrait upside down (180 degrees)?

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-orientation, android-screen

I need to activate something when my device is rotated 180 degrees (getRotation() should return 2). However, the posts I read only say that 0, 90 and 270 degrees are the only angles for which notification is received. Is this device specific? 
What devices return 2?

Comment: Are only interested in the 180 degrees, or will the landscape detection solve your problem?

Comment: My current and previous phones don't do upside down portrait, so I'm guessing device specific.

Answer (score 2):

Whenever you rotate your device, the `onCreate()` method of your activity is called, so you find your device's rotation by calling, on your activity's `onCreate()`:

```
getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getRotation();
```

However, it wont detect the rotation constant 2. According to the API, unspecified is the default value for the orientation:

> The default value. The system chooses the orientation. The policy it
>   uses, and therefore the choices made in specific contexts, may differ
>   from device to device.

Im guessing that `screenOrientation:unspecified` wont detect all 4 angles. From the API we can also see several options, one of them is "fullsensor" and the api states:

> The orientation is determined by the device orientation sensor for any
>   of the 4 orientations. This is similar to "sensor" except this allows
>   any of the 4 possible screen orientations, regardless of what the
>   device will normally do (for example, some devices won't normally use
>   reverse portrait or reverse landscape, but this enables those). Added
>   in API level 9.

So to solve this go to your manifest file and add a screen orientation to your activity, like so:

```
<activity
        android:name="com.example.androidactivitystart.ActivityA"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="fullSensor" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

Now, when you call `getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getRotation();` it will detect all angles, here is my logCat output from the trials I ran:

> 02-12 19:45:30.065: D/cenas(26085): on start called: 1
>
> 02-12 19:45:31.433: D/cenas(26085): on start called: 0
>
> 02-12 19:45:32.678: D/cenas(26085): on start called: 3
>
> 02-12 19:45:34.356: D/cenas(26085): on start called: 2

As you can see all the 4 possible angles were detected. Obviously wont work on device's whose Android version is lower < 9.

Link to the API if you need something else: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#screen